# How to parse a "problematic" CSV in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I've to parse a "problematic" CSV file like this:

```
some text here
other line of text, here
header1, header2, header3
value1, value2, value3  // data row #1
value1, value2, value3  // data row #2
(empty line)
(empty line)
some other text here
```

Of course i'm only interested in rows (value1, value2 and value3) that actually contains valuable data. I've tried to fetch the url into a string and than call `str_getcsv` (default parameters) but what i'm getting is an array that is difficult to work with:

```
array
  0 => string 'some text here ' (length=50)
  1 => string ' other text here
other text here
header1 ' (length=50)
  2 => string 'header2' (length=13)
  3 => string 'header3' (length=14)
  4 => string 'header4' (length=14)
  5 => string '
value1' (length=2)
  6 => string 'value2' (length=1)
  7 => string 'value3' (length=1)
  8 => string 'value4
```

Comment: That's not a valid CSV file. You need to fix the problems (i.e. remove the invalid lines) before you can use fgetcsv on it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster i know. You think i have to skip the first 2 lines at the beginning and the trailing lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that structure is fixed, then you could make an array of lines and then just use the 4th and 5th line.

Try this `$file` is a variable with the content you want to parse.

```
$lines = array();
foreach(preg_split("/(\r?\n)/", $file) as $line){
    $lines[] = $line;
}
$data_row1 = explode(',', $lines[3]);
$data_row1 = explode(',', $lines[4]);
```

Comment: Not so fixed but yes, i've tried and works well. Thanks for the tip. The funny is that this invalid csv came from a government site. LOL.